# How to use limit correctly in Codeigniter Framework PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter

In my project I want to show 3 rows, for which i use `limit('3')`, but when my result is greater then 3, content is not showing.

if i limit increase from 3 to 5 or 6 then items again start to show.

how to fixed this problem, so that if item count is more, it shows just 3?

Here is database code, written into `Model`:

```
public function select_all_contenta()
{

 $this->db->select('*');
 $this->db->from('content');

 $this->db->order_by('date_add','DESC');
 $this->db->limit('3');

 $query_result=$this->db->get();
 $allcontent_infoa=$query_result->result();
 return $allcontent_infoa;
}
```

Comment: What is the output of `var_dump($allcontent_infoa);`?

Answer (score 0):

```
public function select_all_contenta() {
   $this->db->from('content');
   $this->db->order_by('date_add','DESC');
   $this->db->limit('3');
   $query_result = $this->db->get();
   $allcontent_infoa = $query_result->result_array();
   return $allcontent_infoa;
}
```

Comment: You don't need $this->db->select('*');

Answer (score 0):

change

```
   $this->db->limit('3');
```

into

```
   $this->db->limit ( 3 );
```

It should be number not string value (limit the number of rows you would like returned by the query)

Comment: "return array,so u can't assign into signal variable" Really?

Comment: for multiple function if i use multiple foreach statement in one page, is there any conflict to show content

Comment: add
$this->output->enable_profiler ( TRUE );
and check query result..if u don't mind post screenshot..so we could help u

Answer (score 0):

Try to change this code

```
$this->db->limit(2,0); //$this->db->limit(3,0);
```

Answer (score 0):

your code is not optimised.

try this instead

```
public function select_all_contenta()
{
  $q = $this->db->get('content' , 3)->order_by('date_add','DESC');
  return $q->result();
}
```